# Room RxJava observable triggered multiple times on insert

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

I'm having a weird problem with my repository implementation. Every time I call my function that's supposed to get data from the database and update the database with a network call, I receive multiple results from my database observer.

```kotlin
override fun getApplianceControls(
    serialNumber: SerialNumber
): Flowable<ApplianceControlState> {
    val subject = BehaviorProcessor.create<ApplianceControlState>()

    controlsDao.get(serialNumber.serial)
        .map { controls ->
            ApplianceControlState.Loaded(controls.toDomainModel())
        }
        .subscribe(subject)

    controlApi.getApplianceControls(serialNumber.serial)
        .flatMapObservable<ApplianceControlState> { response ->
            val entities = response.toEntity(serialNumber)
            // Store the fetched controls on the database.
            controlsDao.insert(entities).andThen(
                // Return an empty observable because the db will take care of emitting latest values.
                Observable.create { }
            )
        }
        .onErrorResumeNext { error: Throwable ->
            Observable.create { emitter -> emitter.onNext(ApplianceControlState.Error(error)) }
        }
        .subscribeOn(backgroundScheduler)
        .subscribe()


    return subject.distinctUntilChanged()
}
```

```kotlin
@Dao
interface ApplianceControlsDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(controls: List<TemperatureControlEntity>): Completable

    @Query("SELECT * FROM control_temperature WHERE serial = :serial")
    fun get(serial: String): Flowable<List<TemperatureControlEntity>>
}
```

Basically, if I call `getApplianceControls` once, I get desired result. Then I call again, with another serial number, which is empty and I get the empty array. **But then I call a third time,  but with the same serial number as the first time and I get a mix of correct results and empty array after the insert call is made.**

Like this:

1st call, to serial number "123" -> Loaded([control1, control2, control3])

2nd call, to serial number "000" -> Loaded([])

3rd call, to serial number "123" -> Loaded([control1, control2, control3]),  Loaded([]), Loaded([control1, control2, control3])

If I remove the db insert from the api response, it works fine. Everything weird occurs after `insert` is called.

Edit: `getApplianceControls()` is called from the `ViewModel`.

```kotlin
fun loadApplianceControls(serialNumber: SerialNumber) {
    Log.i("Loading appliance controls")

    applianceControlRepository.getApplianceControls(serialNumber)
        .subscribeOn(backgroundScheduler)
        .observeOn(mainScheduler)
        .subscribeBy(
            onError = { error ->
                Log.e("Error $error")
            },
            onNext = { controlState ->
                _controlsLiveData.value = controlState  
            }
        ).addTo(disposeBag)
}
```

Comment: Did tried to replace Flowable with Single? As you are emitting a single data

Comment: @MustafaKhaled yes I tried, but in the long run I want this to be a flowable/observable because the dataset might change due to a push notification from the server

Comment: first of all you have 2 subscriptions which are not unsubscribed anywhere. This could cause memory leak. And can you show where do you use this `fun getApplianceControls()`?

Comment: @borichellow they're subscribed using the subject subscription, which I believe causes them to be disposed when the subject is also disposed (please correct me if I'm wrong). I will edit the question to add where the function is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mention in comment you have 2 subscriptions that are not unsubscribed anywhere, it could cause memory leak (it doesn't dispose when subject is disposed), also with such implementation  you ignore API errors. 
i'd try to change it to:

```
override fun getApplianceControls(serialNumber: SerialNumber): Flowable<ApplianceControlState> {

    val dbObservable = controlsDao.get(serialNumber.serial)
        .map { controls ->
            ApplianceControlState.Loaded(controls.toDomainModel())
        }

    val apiObservable = controlApi.getApplianceControls(serialNumber.serial)
        .map { response ->
            val entities = response.toEntity(serialNumber)
           // Store the fetched controls on the database.
           controlsDao.insert(entities).andThen( Unit )
        }
        .toObservable()
        .startWith(Unit)

    return Observables.combineLatest(dbObservable, apiObservable) { dbData, _ -> dbData }
        // apiObservable emits are ignored, but it will by subscribed with dbObservable and Errors are not ignored 
        .onErrorResumeNext { error: Throwable ->
            Observable.create { emitter -> emitter.onNext(ApplianceControlState.Error(error)) }
        }
        .subscribeOn(backgroundScheduler)
        //observeOn main Thread
        .distinctUntilChanged()
}
```

I'm not sure if it solves the original issue. But if so - the issue is in `flatMapObservable` 
ALSO would be useful to see `controlApi.getApplianceControls()` implementation.

Comment: `controlApi.getApplianceControls()` is from Retrofit, it just returns a `Single<ApplianceControlData>`. I will try your implementation.

Comment: then you need to add `.toObservable()` to make my code works. I edited the answer and added `startWith()` to apiObservable, as `combineLatest` will wait for first emitting from both Observables.

Comment: With this implementation I only receive the result once. It's like the db observable is stuck. Which I believe is the same root cause as my original problem. Each time I call the DAO function it stacked with the last call and I keep receiving multiple results. But with this implementation it's like it's reusing the same observable, but it's stuck.

Comment: then i guess issue is in DB part, and i'm not familiar with Room, sorry

Comment: After tweaking a little bit with your solution it finally worked. I guess i wasn't doing it right and you were right about not unsubscribing correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to be useful